# Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_results()

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my login PHP code

```
<?php

    session_start();

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    include 'dbh.inc.php';

    $uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uid']);
    $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);

    if (empty($uid) || empty($pwd)) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?login=empty");
        exit();
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid= ?";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$user_uid);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_results(); //LINE 20 IS HERE BTW
        $num_rows = $result->num_rows;

        if($num_rows == 1) {

            $rows = $result->fetch_assoc();
            $hashedPwdCheck = password_verify($pwd, $row['user_pwd']);
                if ($hashedPwdCheck == false) {
                    header("Location: ../index.php?login=errorchecker");
                    exit();
                } elseif ($hashedPwdCheck == true) {
                    #Logs in
                    $_SESSION['u_id'] = $row['user_id'];
                    $_SESSION['u_first'] = $row['user_first'];
                    $_SESSION['u_last'] = $row['user_last'];
                    $_SESSION['u_email'] = $row['user_email'];
                    $_SESSION['u_uid'] = $row['user_uid'];
                    header("Location: ../index.php?login=success");
                    exit();
                }

            $read->close();
        } else {
            header("Location: ../index.php?login=errorb4pwcheck");
        }
    }
}
```

Returns the error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_results() in C:\wamp64\www\loginsystem-1\includes\login.inc.php on line 20

```
$result = $stmt->get_results();
```

I have searched as many threads as I can find and have tried different ways on doing this prepared statement, I have seen a lot about mysqlnd not being installed and enabled.
Proof mine is:

[phpinfo on mysqlnd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHcyL.png)

I have tried using the bind & fetch methods but it just simply doesn't work, I'm guessing I am doing it wrong but i've watched many different tutorials and read forum posts about it and tried to apply it to my work.

Comment: So where is `$user_uid` defined or assigned a value ?

Comment: `get_result` [`Available only with mysqlnd.`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php)

Comment: If you are unable to properly install the `mysqlnd` driver, then use standard bindings and fetching. The documentation holds examples on how to do that. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Comment: I do have mysqlnd

Comment: Shouldn't it be `get_result()` (Instead of `get_results()`)?

Comment: @AlonEitan thanks, it did used to be that, i changed it back and it returns me with the errorb4pwcheck, at the else statement at the bottom, so it's failing while doing everything before the `"if($num_rows == 1)`

Comment: @Qirel with the bind and fetch do i start my session and the hashedpwcheck in the while loop?

Comment: @James Well, not the actual query is working. You need to debug and check how many rows that query actually returns (Maybe there are more than one rows with the same `user_uid`?)

Comment: @AlonEitan I cleared my table and then signed up with a new account, went to login and it stil returns the same error. (Could it possibly something to do with my selecting *)

Comment: @James I don't know. You need to debug the code - check the value of `$user_id` because I don't see it anywhere in your code. Also, try it with `$stmt->bind_param("s",$_POST['uid']);` (You don't need to escape the string when you're using prepared statements)

Comment: @AlonEitan Yeah, again where I have tried so many different methods I forgot to add some things. It does not work with `$_POST['uid']|);`. Thanks and i will carry on trying to debug

Comment: @AlonEitan I have managed to get it to return the `index.php?login=errorchecker` I believe there is an issue when comparing the hashed passwords. My theory is, that it is somehow trying to compare plain text password that was entered, to the hashed password in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution code my friend helped me solve :) Just incase anyone experienced the same issue...

```
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

include 'dbh.inc.php';

$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

# Error handlers
# Check if inputs are empty
if (empty($uid) || empty($pwd)) {
    header("Location: ../index.php?login=empty");
    exit();
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid= ?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['uid']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $num_rows = $result->num_rows;

    if($num_rows == 1) {

        while ($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            if (!password_verify($pwd, $rows['user_pwd'])) {
                header("Location: ../index.php?login=errorchecker");
                exit();
            } else {
                #Logs in
                $_SESSION['u_id'] = $rows['user_id'];
                $_SESSION['u_first'] = $rows['user_first'];
                $_SESSION['u_last'] = $rows['user_last'];
                $_SESSION['u_email'] = $rows['user_email'];
                $_SESSION['u_uid'] = $rows['user_uid'];
                header("Location: ../index.php?login=success");
                exit();
            }
        }

        $read->close();
    } else {
        header("Location: ../index.php?login=errorb4pwcheck");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: same code I have. I'm still getting error 'PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() '  here=> '$result = $stmt->get_result();'